# Fastlane: Run iOS unit test without build

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane

I have fastlane setup which builds app for UI test & unit test.
Problem is that when I run `fastlane build` (to generate .app file for ui test) and `fastlane test` (for unit test), it's building project 2 times.
So my question is, is there anyway to unit test iOS app without building project again(maybe we can use build output from `fastlane build` command)?

Thanks

```
desc "Build for UI tests"
lane :build do
  xcbuild(
     workspace: "test.xcworkspace",
     scheme: "Debug",
     configuration: "Debug",
  )
end

desc "Run Swift tests"
lane :test do
  scan(
    scheme: "AppTests"
  )
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scan` for building too and `derived_data_path` parameter to share compiled sources. Something like this:

```
desc "Build for UI tests"
lane :build do
  scan(
    workspace: "test.xcworkspace",
    scheme: "Debug",
    skip_build: false,
    derived_data_path: "derived_data",
    build_for_testing: true
  )
end

desc "Run Swift tests"
lane :test do
  scan(
    workspace: "test.xcworkspace",
    scheme: "AppTests",
    test_without_building: true
    derived_data_path: "derived_data"
  )
end
```