# Will not do cross-module incremental builds

Tags: xcode, xcode14.3

Since using Xcode 14.3 I get the following warnings while building a project as usual:

`Will not do cross-module incremental builds, priors saved at TimePoint(seconds: 1682802841, nanoseconds: 0)), but the previous build started at TimePoint(seconds: 1682802841, nanoseconds: 665285000), at '/Volumes/DerivedData-ramdisk/PlayingAround3-bxofrzjmlkadwicxzlwhcctqhimt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PlayingAroundPagage.build/Debug/Interleaf.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Interleaf-master.priors'`

This seems to suggest that the previous build started 665285000 nanoseconds in the future so I get that Xcode might have an issue.. I might have interpreted this wrong though. Can I fix the warning somehow?

Answer (score 20):

The warnings went away after I built the project from clean (In XCode Menu `Product` > `Clean Build Folder...`).

I think this warning has to do with building the project using a newer version of Xcode when there are still build products sitting around from an older version of Xcode.

Comment: Interestingly it is appeared after first clean and build, and gone after second clean and build.

Answer (score -1):

Might be related to putting the Xcode build folder on a ramdisk, which was not an issue before and does not seem to be now either, with just the warning being a bit annoying.

Seems to be fixed with Xcode 15.0 beta. Haven't found a solution for 14.3.

Comment: Hmm I am still seeing this warning on Xcode 15.0 beta 6